# Could not find a version that matches pathspec

Tags: python, django, pipenv

There was a problem downloading awsebcli to deploy the Django project on AWS.

```
pipenv install awsebcli
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Esjr.png)

this is my pipfile

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
flake8 = "*"
black = "*"

[packages]
pathspec = "== 0.5.9"
django = "==3.0.3"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"

[pipenv]
allow_prereleases = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Pipfile and re-install project dependencies and generate a new Pipfile:

```
pipenv --rm 
rm Pipfile
rm Pipfile.lock 
pipenv install pathspec django
```

related issues:

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3549

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3705

Comment: Glad to help :), consider accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I want to vote, but I don't have enough reputation:(                                                       I don't know much when asking about stack overflow for the first time.                            But if you wait, I'll find a way and vote:)

Comment: It's ok move on; just wanted to say you can check this answer as accepted if it was helpful.